# How to get git branch at commit with tag at run Azure pipeline?

Tags: tags, azure-pipelines, branch, commit, git-branch

In Azure Pipeline is possible use predefined build variables (DevOps Services) Build.SourceBranch and Build.SourceBranchName but their values at case commit with tag are tags.

In doc. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#build-variables-devops-services is written

- When your pipeline is triggered by a tag: refs/tags/your-tag-name
- The name of the branch in the triggering repo the build was queued for.
  Git repo branch or pull request: The last path segment in the ref. For example, in refs/heads/master this value is master. In refs/heads/feature/tools this value is tools.

- this my observation: but in case commit with tag is the last path segment of Build.SourceBranch, so your-tag-name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it is described in the document. If the pipeline is triggered by a tag. Then variables Build.SourceBranch and Build.SourceBranchName will be the tag name.

However, you can use git commands(`git branch -r --contains $(Build.SourceBranchName) | grep -v $(Build.SourceVersion)`) to retrieve the branch name that the tag points to.

If you want to use the branch name as variable, You can define a variable use the [logging commands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#set-variables-in-scripts)(`echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=CurrentBranch]$branch"`). For below example:

```
- powershell: |
     #get the branch name
     $branch = git branch -r --contains $(Build.SourceBranchName) | grep -v $(Build.SourceVersion)
     
     #define varialbe CurrentBranch to hold the value.
     echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=CurrentBranch]$branch" 

- powershell: echo "$(CurrentBranch)"  #use the branch name in the following steps by referring to $(CurrentBranch)
```